# Comparing three values from client side with the other three values in the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am still new in asp programming and i am having difficulty in figuring how to compare the values from client side with the database.

For example, i am going to insert `date`, `starttime` and `room` values into the database but under one condition which they cannot be the same with the `date`, `starttime` and `room` values that has already exist in the database.

Much thanks !

Comment: did you try to make a query at the server side (before inserting) to check if the values already exists in database?

Comment: How are you interacting with the database?

Comment: @MohammadAli now that make sense... I'm gonna try it first

Comment: @H.Mustafa if you find my comment is the solution, please tell me so I move it to a solution proposal and you can mark it as a solution

Comment: You could make those three fields a composite key. When you insert a new entry, you'll need to try/catch the (sql-)exception, telling you, that the composed key may already exists. That way - before inserting - you dont need to check, if it exists. You just write an entry, if it rises an exeption, you need to handle it. Otherwise you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all see whether the similar entry already exist in table or not. If similar entry is not exist in table only then you may provide entry into databse.

Make similar query as below:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM yourTable 
> WHERE date = yourDate 
> AND starttime =  yourStarttime 
> AND room == yourRoom
> ```

If returned result from above query is `NULL` then make entry into database , otherwise skip entry operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if exists(select * from tablename where date = date and starttime = starttime and date=date)
 begin
---   insert (here It Check data is There If there in begin statement U can insert
 end
else
 begin
 --if any operation if No data there 
end
```

or

```
 if exists(select * from tablename where date = date and starttime = 
  starttime and date=date)
 begin
       declare @count int ;
       set count=  select count(*) from tablename where date = date and starttime=starttime and date=date
       if(@count ==0 )
           begin
                -- Count is Zero
                ---   insert (here It Check data is There If there in begin statement U can 
           end 
       else
           begin 
                -- Count more than Zero 
           end
  end
  else
  begin
        --if any operation if No data there 
  end
```